# Can't execute CGI Script on phpnet.org hosting

Tags: cgi

I need to execute CGI script to run my Bugzilla on a phpnet.org hosting. CGI scripts are only show to me.

I know i can do it. It's show on http://www.phpnet.org/mutualise.php i have a premimum standard hosting.

I dont have root right to modify apache configuration. I can't use apt get.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Does your script name end in `.php`? Do you use the FULL tag `<?php` to start PHP code?

Comment: I dont understand. It's not my script, it's the bugzilla index.cgi script. Why we need php?

Comment: Can you create a file called `.htaccess` in the root directory where you serve documents from and include the following line `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`

Comment: Ok, i try this and i get a 403 forbidden.
So i add :
<Directory>
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
In my bugzilla root directory. I get :
[Tue Sep 09 11:16:15 2014] [alert] [client 88.163.59.208] /home/www/bugzilla/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here.
After, i try the same in my www directory. i get :
[Tue Sep 09 11:26:13 2014] [alert] [client 88.163.59.208] /home/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's solved.

I add

`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks`

in my .htaccess file in bugzilla root directory.
Thanks Mark